# Hive query Error -- FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:117 Invalid table alias or column reference state

Tags: hadoop, hive

Getting this error

```
hive> insert overwrite table employees_partition partition (country ='IND', State='HR') select * from employees_data where state = 'Haryana';     
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:117 Invalid table alias or column reference state
```

My partitioned table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE employees_partition (
name STRING,
salary FLOAT,
subordinates ARRAY<STRING>,
deductions MAP<STRING, FLOAT>,
address STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, zip:INT>) PARTITIONED BY (country STRING, state STRING) 
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '$'
map keys terminated by '#';
```

Comment: The error message refers to **Line 1:117** i.e. WHERE clause about column `state` in table `employee_data`. **Did you test that SELECT query?**

Answer (score 0):

To remove this error you have to execute following commands on your hive shell:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
```

#### Reasons for this error:

By default, the `hive.exec.dynamic.partition` configuration property is set to "False" and `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode` is set to "strict" because Hive versions <0.9.0 could not perform dynamic partition.